# Wordpress show post from same category same month

Tags: wordpress, categories

I need to show something like this in the single template, if the post is in the magazine category show all the post that was published in same month from only that category. I tried the following:

```
    <?php
    $current_year = get_the_date('j',$the_post->post_parent);
    $current_month = get_the_date('F',$the_post->post_parent);
    query_posts($query_string . '&cat=1700&order=DESC&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month');
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To begin do not use `query_posts` its not problematic and IMO lackluster ;) more on that [**here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Try this:

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array('monthnum' => $today["mon"], 'cat' => 1700, 'order' => 'DESC', 'year' => $today["year"]);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
echo '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```